# Making concurring folders via terminal

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal

I want to make `crontab` make concurring folders, like this:
Every Monday the tab must create a new folder, but it has to add the number otherwise it will overwrite each other.

The numbers could be the date of each Monday.

```
--

Week one makes folder:

Monday_01

--

Week two makes folder:

Monday_02

--

Week three makes folder:

Monday_03

--
```

Cant find anything online about it.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be improved by explaining a bit more about the requirements. Are the asterisks supposed to be part of the name (bad idea, IMHO, if so)? Is the `2020` a subdirectory under the `Monday_##`? How many `Monday_##` folders are there supposed to be? What do the "--" entries indicate?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. Since to me an ever increasing directory full of "Monday_" would be not that easy to navigate, I'd probably set up something like (change `tmp` to the desired base directory):

```
 1 0 * * 1 mkdir -p "/tmp/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%A)_$(date +%V)"
```

So I would get a result of:

```
 2020/
   Monday_01
   Monday_02
   etc.
```

where the number corresponds to the week number. In that way, I'd have the directories by year, and the number itself would convey some positive information.

The next best approach would be to write a script in one's language of choice, and use the scripting capability to parse the number and increment it. Such an approach would also handle some potential issues of the format (what happens when the accumulated directories get to > 99? Then it will be _100, and standard sorting will start to get confusing, I would think), as well as provide (potentially) better error handling.

If one must stay in the realm of `cron` (well, such as it is), this approach should work, though it will have much reduced error checking compared to writing a script.

```
 val=$(/bin/ls -1rtd /tmp/Monday_* | tail -n1 | cut -d'_' -f2) \
   && printf -v nv "%02d" $((10#$val + 1)) \
   && mkdir "/tmp/Monday_$nv"
```

This works by finding the latest<sup>1</sup> "Monday_*" directory (adjust "/tmp" for base directory), splitting on the underscore character ("_"), formatting the incremented value (again, not sure what is supposed to happen once one gets to 99), and then making the directory. The `10#` is needed to avoid issues with leading `0` in the value (which would get interpreted as octal otherwise).

Some example output, along with the standard sort wonkiness:

```
/tmp/Monday_01/
/tmp/Monday_02/
/tmp/Monday_03/
/tmp/Monday_04/
/tmp/Monday_05/
/tmp/Monday_06/
/tmp/Monday_07/
/tmp/Monday_08/
/tmp/Monday_09/
/tmp/Monday_10/
/tmp/Monday_100/
/tmp/Monday_101/
/tmp/Monday_102/
/tmp/Monday_103/
/tmp/Monday_104/
/tmp/Monday_105/
/tmp/Monday_106/
/tmp/Monday_107/
/tmp/Monday_108/
/tmp/Monday_109/
/tmp/Monday_11/
```

Use the same cron format (1 0 * * 1) to invoke this every Monday morning at 1 minute past midnight.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, latest is defined by the creation time. Since the requirement was to create a new directory every Monday, using the latest time should be OK. As noted, standard sorting is going to get wonky once the files go past 99 (if using `%02` as the format).